# Could not build module GoogleMobileAds on ios 6.1

Tags: objective-c, ios6.1

I am trying to create a demo ios project based on https://developers.google.com/mobile-ads-sdk/docs/admob/ios/quick-start

Everything works if i choose iphone 5 simulator to build and run the app, but when i try building the project for my ipod touch 4g (ios 6.1), it doesn't build and gives error "**Could not build module GoogleMobileAds**"

i am importing the mobile as :
@import GoogleMobileAds;

I am using GoogleMobileAds SDK version 7.2.1 .

Looking for the solution.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have done following things it works fine.

goto build settings and say yes to always search user path.

then put your google mobile ads local path on frame work search path.